# error insert data in java netbeans and mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am a beginner in learning programming and I am trying to apply what I learned with an application example in java , and I encountered a problem. I hope you will find a solution, please.
When I insert data the combobox (combo_produits) it doesn't give me the specified value,
The code has no errors, but the combobox does not give us the desired value despite using the function getSelectedIndex() .

```
/*method of combobox combo_produits */
   private void combo_PRODUIT() {

       try {
           String qyP = "SELECT CONCAT(NOM_COM,'  ',lib_court,' ',DOSAGE ,' ',UNITE , ' ', CONDIT)AS DESIGNATION "
                   + "FROM produit  JOIN forme USING(cd_forme) ";
           prs_sort = connectio.prepareStatement(qyP);
           rs_sort = prs_sort.executeQuery();
           while (rs_sort.next()) {
               combo_produits.addItem(rs_sort.getString("DESIGNATION"));

           }

       } catch (Exception exp) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp.getMessage());
       }

   }

/* button of insert */
    private void valider_bpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

       int pharID = 0;
       int donid = 0;
       int lotID = 0;
       int prodid= 0 ;

       try {
           String qr1 = "insert into tbl_pharmacien (NOM_PHARM) values ('" + combo_pharm.getSelectedItem() + "')";
           prs_sort = connectio.prepareStatement(qr1, prs_sort.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
           prs_sort.executeUpdate();
           rs_sort = prs_sort.getGeneratedKeys();
           while (rs_sort.next()) {

               pharID = rs_sort.getInt(1);
           }

           String qr2 = "insert into donner_medic (PHARM_ID , DATE_ECHANDONN) values "
                   + "('" + pharID + "', '" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date_prod_sort.getDate()) + "' )";
           prs_sort = connectio.prepareStatement(qr2, prs_sort.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
           prs_sort.executeUpdate();
           rs_sort = prs_sort.getGeneratedKeys();
           while (rs_sort.next()) {

               donid = rs_sort.getInt(1);

              
           }

           int index =combo_produits.getSelectedIndex();
           

           String qr3 = " insert into tbl_lot (NUM_ENR,PPA, QNT) values "
                   + "('" +index  + "', '" + txtf_ppa.getText() + "', '" + txt_Qnt.getText() + "' )";
           prs_sort = connectio.prepareStatement(qr3, prs_sort.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
           prs_sort.executeUpdate();
           rs_sort = prs_sort.getGeneratedKeys();
           while (rs_sort.next()) {

               lotID = rs_sort.getInt(1);
           }

           String qr4 = "insert into tbl_donnelot (LOT_ID,DONN_ID) values ('" + lotID + "', '" + donid + "')";
           prs_sort = connectio.prepareStatement(qr4);
           prs_sort.executeUpdate();

       } catch (Exception exp) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp.getMessage());
       }

       Table_prod_sort();
   }
```

Comment: You should learn how to use [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) properly with parameters for better and cleaner code. Also, have you checked that your sql queries executes fine by themselves by using a mysql client?

Comment: You are inserting the *index* of the selected item into your database? That hardly makes sense. So if the items are 1 Toothbrush, 4 Pain killer and 6 Hand creme and I select the pain killer, then you insert 1 because the pain killer is at index 1. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Everything works fine, but the solution is going on in front of me, but as a start, I need time

Comment: When we choose, for example, a pain reliever that has the index number 4, it is in fact in another form called the drug form, but in this form it gives us another drug at the index.

Answer (score 0):

For example let's create a compobox with the student's name:
First, we work a class with the student's name and id for him, and we do the Setter, getter and Constructor functions.
Second, we create a function to link the database with the students' class, thus:

```
public class class_array {
         private Connection co=get_connection.ConnDb() ;
  private  PreparedStatement prst ;
   private ResultSet res ;
    
     public HashMap<String, Integer> fillCombobox(){
        String sqls = "SELECT `ID_student`, `Name_student` FROM `student`";
    HashMap<String, Integer> hmp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
       try {
           prst = co.prepareStatement(sqls);
           res = prst.executeQuery();
           student st ;
           while(res.next()){
               st = new student(res.getInt(1), res.getString(2));
               hmp.put(st.getName_stud(), st.getId_stu());
           }
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(student_f.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
    
    return hmp ;
    }}
```

Third, in the form we write the compobox content display function like this :

```
private void combo(){
        class_array std = new class_array();
     HashMap<String, Integer> hmp = std.fillCombobox();
        for (String cb :hmp.keySet()) {
            combo_st.addItem(cb);
        }
        
    }
```

And finally, like in the previous example, we want to use the last Selection  of combobox , so we write the following:

```
 private void bp_valid_indexActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
       
        class_array stb = new class_array();
        HashMap<String,Integer> has = stb.fillCombobox();
        int index = has.get(combo_st.getSelectedItem().toString()).toString();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution, and it lies in displaying the content of the combobox with linking it to the number of his id, so that when we work getSelectedItem the value of the combobox is selected with his id